# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException - ArrayLength

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, indexoutofboundsexception, swap

[Please click here to see my task's screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lEJ2h.png)

Hello, could you please help me? What is wrong with my code? I understand that there is something wrong in my Array's length or my If statement, but i couldnot able to find out it.

Thank you very much!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

 class TripleSwapping {

 public static void main(String[] args) {

     Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.println("Please enter the count of your elements: ");
     int count = in.nextInt();

     System.out.println("Your array before sorting: ");
     int A[] = new int [count];
     for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
         A[i]=in.nextInt();
    }
     boolean changed =false;
     do {
         for (int i = 0; i < A.length-1; i++) {
             if (!(A[i+1]>A[i]) && !(A[i+1] > A[i+2])) {
                 int temp;
                 temp = A[i];
                 A[i]= A[i+1];
                 A[i+1] =temp;
               }
         }
         for (int i = 0; i < A.length-1; i++) {
             if (A[i] >A[i+1]) {
                  int temp;
                 temp = A[i];
                 A[i]= A[i+1];
                 A[i+1] =temp;
               changed=true;  
             }

         }


     }while(changed);

     System.out.println("Your array after swapping");

     for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
         System.out.println(A[i]);
     }

}

}
```

Comment: Please copy and paste your code into your question. Please do not link to an *image* of your *text book.*  That doesn't help.

Comment: @markspace yes, i have forgotten to add my code, now i added, thank you very much for reminding me:)

Comment: Doesn't the error tell you on which line you are out of bounds?

Comment: The easiest culprit I can see is when assigning the `count` variable: `int count = in.nextInt()`. If you read an int that is less than 10, then the for loop you do next: `for (int i =0; i<10; i++)` will throw an exception.

Comment: Well, also need the exception trace -- the full text from the exception you get.  It should have the line number there.  Also please indicate with a comment which line is the actual error, because we can't see the line numbers from your code.

Comment: It shows me this line :  if (!(A[i+1]>A[i]) && !(A[i+1] > A[i+2]))

Comment: `i+1` will obviously throw an error if `i` is equal to `A.length`-1. `i+2` is right out.

Comment: Yes, i understand that is because of A[i+1], but what i should write based on my task?

Comment: What is your task?  You're trying to sort the array?

Comment: I have added screenshot photo to this post, it is not shown?

Comment: Screenshots disappear.  Please add in your own words what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: P.S. In other words I'm trying to explain how to ask a good question and get a good answer.  This is all stuff (include code, don't use screenshots instead of text) that will get you dinged on other questions as well, so might as well get used to posting this way now.

Comment: I updated, and now you can see my screenshot

Answer (score 0):

You are getting ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException because if you enter to be less than 10 it will throw an exception.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    A[i]=in.nextInt();
}
```

Used instead

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    A[i]=in.nextInt();
}
```

Comment: Better is to use `i < A.length`.  Less chance of getting an error because `count` got reassigned to some other value.

Comment: yeah !! also you can have a check for `0` value

Comment: what did you give input ?